# How to determine path to resources in java web application

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I'm writing a simple web application using Spring MVC Apache Tiles and Bootstrap and I'm having trouble with loading CSS and images. For deploying I use jetty server.
My project structure look like following:
[image: project structure]

My tiles config file looks

```
<definition name="common" template="/WEB-INF/layout/classic.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layout/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="index" extends="common">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Car Store" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp" />
</definition>
```

And when I try to include css file in my `classic.jsp`, browser can't find relative resources. I try two cases like following

```
<link href="/WEB-INF/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and

```
<link href="../css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but error still throw.
Spring controller method looks:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index(){
    return "index";
}
```

Dispatcher servlet config file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.yurabilash.car.store.controller"/>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I suggest you give http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/ a read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/WEB-INF/` directory is not supposed to be accessible from client. Move your static resources like `css` and `img` to the `webapp` root.